# How to calculate more than one variable in poly?

Tags: python

```
coef=[1,-1,1]
var=[0,1,5]


def poly(coef, var):
    try:
        return [poly(coef, x) for x in var]
    except TypeError:
        sum = 0
        xp =1 
        for a in coef:
            sum += a *xp 
            xp = var* xp 
        return sum

print(poly(coef,var))
```

but it doesn't work because
function does not notice leading coefficient

ı change the coef this [2,-1,1] and print is [2, 2, 22].multiply the function by that number instead of the leading coefficient

Comment: using recursion in list comprehension is bad idead

Comment: I must admit I don't get what you are trying to achieve. Btw : should you name the params of your func c and v. I guess it's a bit messing up with the lists declared in the global scope.

Comment: As pointed by sahasrara62, the recursive call in the list comprehension does not help clarifying that

Comment: so how do i do it .according to the title.actually it is a question for you

Comment: Before the how, the question is to clarify the what ? Maybe you should say with words what you want to do...

Comment: I want the list of values ​​we give to the polynomial function.(
The coef list expresses the coefficients of the polynomial)

Comment: So the expected output should be `1*0 + -1*1 + 1*5`?

Comment: with `coeff = [1,2,3]`, `poly` would be `lambda x:1+2*x+3*x**2` I guess ?

Comment: Do you know some functional programming aspects ? 'cause if your point is to construct the polynomial from the coefs list and then evaluate this function on the val list, this can be achieved quite easily.

Comment: I know about it but have no idea how to apply it.
I feel like a bullet waiting to be fired

Comment: I ran the function with `coef = [1, -1, 1]` and `coef = [2, -1, 1]` and the results are different, so why do you mean by "function does not notice leading coefficient"?

Answer (score 0):

```py
from functools import reduce


monom = lambda k:lambda x:x**k
scal = lambda k,fun: lambda x:k*fun(x)
add = lambda f1, f2 : lambda x:f1(x)+f2(x)
zero = lambda x:0

coeffs = [0,2,3]
monomes = [scal(c,monom(i)) for i,c in enumerate(coeffs)]
poly = reduce(add,monomes,zero)

#you can then map poly on vals
vals=[0,1,5]
results = list(map(poly, vals))
```

Comment: For the sake of argument is x**3+5*x+7 what can ı do yours

Comment: In my code, if everything went ok, `monomes` should point to `[lambda x:0, lambda x:2*x, lambda x: 3*x**2]` wich is maybe not what you intended, but what I understood you wanted.

Comment: if i try to understand your question, if you want `poly` to be `lambda x:7 + 5*x+x**3`, you would take `coeffs = [7, 5, 0, 1]`